# Can I support `labelsHidden` modifier in custom view/style?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewmodifier

I have a custom Toggle style but it doesn't work with `labelsHidden()` view modifier. Is it possible to support it?
I know that I can add a property to my style or hide it right in the body, but I wondering if I can support exactly this modifier

Comment: Please try to give an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ...how? What would look like a good minimal reproducible example here?

Comment: @TheLivingForce it is code that anyone else can run in a newly created project and reproduce the problem. In this case `labelsHidden` should be applied but has no effect.

Comment: @PylypDukhov I see. Is it acceptable for me to edit the question to include one?

Comment: @TheLivingForce no, just create a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LabeledContent` in your custom `ToggleStyle`. When you call `labelsHidden()` modifier, label will not be visible:

```
struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        LabeledContent(
            content: {
                ZStack {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 64, height: 32)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(configuration.isOn ? .green : .white)
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                        .animation(.bouncy, value: configuration.isOn)
                        .offset(x: configuration.isOn ? 16 : -16)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    configuration.isOn.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                configuration.label
            }
        )
    }
}

Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $isOn)
   .toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle())
   .labelsHidden()
```